# Выделение слов из субтитров с ютуба

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Есть аддоны для браузера, которые переводят выделенные слова двойным нажатием на слово (лично я использую simple translate на firefox), но выдеить слово на ютуб не получается, можно только перетащить субтитры. Как сделать возможным выделения субтитров как обычного текста на ютубе? Может это невозможно, я в этом не шарю, буду рад если вы оправергните этот тезис, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В теории можно реализовать. Но для этого надо залазить в потроха [Youtube плеера](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started), переопределять встроенный JS, разспаршивать фразы по нажатию на абзацы. (Оно в субтитры выводит предложения а не слова) и потом уже забирать и переводить, но это крайне сложно. За бесплатно ни кто такое делать явно не будет, но вы можете реализовать.

Comment: У меня была идея по шаманить в коде элемента, может это решение? Или я пургу сморозил XD?

Comment: Youtube Плеер это закрытый элемент к функционалу которого есть ограничиный доступ. Поищите, может есть такое. Мне с субтитрами не доводилось работать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!